# Лексические и Синтаксические ошибки

Tags: лексика, синтаксис

Помогите исправить лексические ошибки.
Достоевский-замечательный психиатр.
И руку ты перчаткой надеваеш, коль на руку перчатку одеваеш.
Коренные аборигены не ограничеваются только охраной тайги.
А так же Синтаксические ошибки.
Садясь за руль машина должна быть в полной исправности.
Согласно последнего приказа сессия продлевается на неделю.
Доклад подготовил ведущий специалист лаборатории Сотова.
Докладчик подчеркнул о необходимости строительства.

Comment: Хорошо бы вам для начала исправить ошибки орфографические.

Answer (score 1):

Откуда этот ад? Вы хотите, чтобы здесь выполняли Ваши учебные задания за Вас? Тут так не делают.

Answer (score 0):

И руку ты перчаткой одеваешь, коль на руку перчатку надеваешь. Коренные жители (или аборигены) не ограничиваются только охраной тайги. (Не могу понять, почему аборигены тайгу охраняют?)
Когда ты садишься за руль, машина должна быть в полной исправности. 
Согласно последнЕМУ приказУ, сессия продлевается на неделю. Доклад подготовилА ведущий специалист лаборатории Сотова. Докладчик подчеркнул  необходимостЬ строительства...
Может быть, так?